# ReferenceError: {var} is not defined

Tags: magento2, blocks, frontend, frontend-model, field

I have a problem with the `frontend_model` of the `system.xml`

This is the `system.xml`

```
<field id="words" translate="label" sortOrder="92" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Dizionario</label>
                <frontend_model>TryAgain\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field\AdditionalItem</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>TryAgain\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend\AdditionalItem</backend_model>
            </field>
```

This is the TryAgain`\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field\AdditionalItem`

```
<?php
 namespace TryAgain\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field;

 use 
Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

class AdditionalItem extends AbstractFieldArray
{
protected function _prepareToRender()
{
    $this->addColumn('noi', ['label' => __('NOI'),'readonly'=>'readonly']);
    $this->addColumn('fixed', ['label' => __('Fixed')]);
    $this->addColumn('percent', ['label' => __('Percent')]);
    $this->_addAfter = false;
    $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add More');
}
}
```

The problem is that when I go to change the name of the column ('we', 'fixed' or 'percent')
[image]I have this error and can no longer save the configurations

[image]

Comment: are you using any library?

Comment: No, I'm not using library

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of the configuration that you are working on in `core_config_data`. This error appears when the keys saved in the database aren't the same as the columns in your PHP class.

So check the value of the 'words' (your sample config key) config in the `core_config_data` table. Notice the keys these should be the same as your columns you defined in `TryAgain\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field`.